# Including an image as an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, images

Say the OP asks for the proof of a particular theorem, the answer to which I have in one of my books, but which is really lengthy and requires lot of math formatting. Is it OK if I just take snapshots of that proof and post those images as answer?

Comment: Very similar older question: [On the inclusion of pages-of-text-as-images in answers](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495/on-the-inclusion-of-pages-of-text-as-images-in-answers)

Comment: Yeah, it does answer my question. Thanks!